# How to deal with web crawlers/parser when using a frontend translation framework?

Tags: javascript, templates, internationalization, translation

All javascript translation system have some sort of key-value array classified by language. Then in the html you can invoke the translation function doing something like `$.i18n( 'message_hello' );` or using a templating system like `<p>{{message_hello}}</p>`.

The thing is, if a web crawler like the Google Bot or the Facebook parser when you hit the Share Button, those do not execute JS, so they are going to parse an unmodified version of the DOM.

How do you deal with this problem?

Comment: Google Bot nowadays does execute JS, but that's not the answer you are a looking for. Would be interested in this myself.

Comment: https://www.lullabot.com/articles/what-is-an-isomorphic-application